# Uncaught TypeError: myCategories.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

For a schoolproject I'm trying to make a quiz app.
It's kinda going well but I'm struggling for a way to write a function that allows me to select a category and change it's appearance. I'm pretty certain I'm doing nothing wrong but Firefox tells me something different...

My HTML:

```
<div id="Category">
   <h2>Kies een categorie</h2>
        <div id="categories">
           <button id="But1" class="catbut">HTML</button>
           <button id="But2" class="catbut">Javascript</button>
           <button id="But3" class="catbut">PHP</button>
           <button id="But4" class="catbut">WordPress</button>
           <button id="But5" class="catbut">MySQL</button>
           <button id="But6" class="catbut">Linux</button>
           <button id="But7" class="catbut">BASH</button>
           <button id="But8" class="catbut">Docker</button> 
        </div>     
 </div>
```

```
const myCategories = document.getElementById("categories")

myCategories.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let aangeduid = e.target;
    let gekozenCategorie = myCategories ? "catbutSelected" : "catbut";
    aangeduid.parentElement.classList.add(gekozenCategorie);
  });
});
```

Comment: `getElementById()` (notice the singular "Element") returns *one* element only. Methods that mention "Element**s**" return multiple which you can use `.forEach()` on. See [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845)

Answer (score 1):

```
const myCategories = document.getElementById("categories")
```

This will get just one item and forEach ofc does not exist for an item.

You need something like:

```
const myCategories = document.querySelectorAll(".catbut")
```

or to have a more specific selector, depends on your needs like "#categories .catbut" or similiar

Comment: Okay that kinda worked :p
Now it just gave the whole button container a background but I need to get it for the clicked button

Comment: Ok thats because you are accessing  aangeduid.parentElement. You dont need parent element at all. just try with  aangeduid.classList.add(gekozenCategorie);

Comment: That worked again. Now is the point that only one button can be toggled/selected. I can click on multiple buttons to select them but I can't put them back to unselected.

Comment: Not sure what you meant? If you want to have also unselected functionality as well you can just instead of classList.add use classList.toggle. If this does not work for you you have to explain it to me in more details what you wanna achieve?

Comment: So the point is that one of those buttons represent a category. If a category is selected, some questions will be fetched from an IPA with the subject of that category that the user selected. You see where I'm going to?

Comment: In that case you have to iterate through all the categories and see which one is selected (in this case if button has a certain class then its selected). Another and better option (but requires more coding skills) is to use checkboxes. I gave you a direction where to go, but i do not want to write the whole code for you. You have to try it and spend some time on that, and if its too dificult then you can post what you did and someone will help you

Comment: Can you just give me the best way to iterate through the categories please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238613/discussion-between-munleashed-and-stef-verniers).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6134z8mL/

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of items you can use

```
const myCategories = document.getElementsByClassName("catbut");
```

That will select all items with class "catbut"

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp